# how to call a service in another module using $on and $broadcast

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do a call from factory A to factory B using angular's $broadcast. These two factories are defined in separate modules.. Below is the code that attempts to do this.

```
angular.module('secondApp', [])
  .service('B', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.$on('test', function(event, data) {
        console.log(event, data);
    });
});

var app = angular.module('firstApp', ['secondApp']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, A) {
    $scope.test = function() {
        A.test();
    };
});

app.service('A', function($rootScope) {
    this.test = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('test', 'Hello from service A!');
    };
});
```

Comment: You unfortunately cannot communicate cross-module using broadcast/on. They simply run up through the scopes until $rootScope, and each module has its own unique $rootScope.

Comment: Thanks Zack Argle, how do you propose I should go about achieving this Cross-module communication?

Comment: I would try with a pub-sub service, maybe [this](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-pubsub) can give you some ideas ;)

Comment: The only way to communicate cross module is by dependency injecting one into the other.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$rootScope.$emit()` instead of `$rootScope.$broadcast()`.

Because `$rootScope.$broadcast()` will despatch downwards.

**Edit:**

Made a sample code to test emit/broadcast/on base on Angular guide: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EExiXyyh7XuYjsb21lM4?p=preview).

Turns out that using `$rootScope.$on` to listen event will be triggered by `$rootScope.$emit` and `$rootScope.$broadcast`. The difference is `$broadcast` will dispatch downwards, so all scopes will receive the event also.

So if you just want to notify `$rootScope`, just using `$rootScope.$emit`. `$rootScope.$broadcast` will waste resource.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer J.C Li but it's still not working.  Please check the codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lvECf

Comment: You can't talk cross module. The $rootScopes are different, so the events never reach eachother.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Please refer my update. Also from angular docs: `Each Angular application has exactly one root scope, but may have several child scopes`.